# Extraer dato de tabla a otra tabla automaticamente en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo un campo llamado **HORA** con el tipo de datos **datetime** y esta predeterminado **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**.

El resultado cuando ingreso un registro sale de este manera **2017-12-20 09:45:00** pero lo que deseo es que en otra tabla me guarde solo la hora en especifico.

Hay alguna manera de resolver este problema?

Nota: Intente usar solo el tipo de datos **time** pero este no acepta el **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He resuelto el problema tomando la idea de Bruno Sosa.

En MySQL deben ir a disparadores, luego crear el nombre del trigger, seleccionar la tabla, en tiempo colocar before y en evento insert.

En definición colocar este codigo:

```
IF NEW.Hora = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
SET NEW.HoraX =CURRENT_TIME();
END IF
```

Y automáticamente me guarda solo la hora.

Comment: Si te sirvio mi respuesta , por favor dale click en respuesta aceptada en el tilde de aceptar respuesta , asi como lo hiciste es por medio de la consola grafica pero si abris una query y escribis lo de arriba y solo cambias el codigo del begin al end te anda tambien

Answer (score 2):

Podrias crear un TRIGGER el cual es un disparador , lo que significa que este codigo que escribas en el trigger se ejecutara despues de un evento X que vas a especificar en este caso es AFTER INSERT ,

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER nombre_del_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON `nombreDeTabla1` for each row
begin
INSERT INTO nombreDeTabla@ (Kind, Type, Sno, Status)
Values (new.Kind, new.Type, new.Sno, 'Available');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Para obtener los datos que vienen en el insert con la hora completa debes poner new.MasElNombreDeLaColumna // y para quedarte solo con la fecha sin la hora , puedes realizarle un substring sabes que las fechas tendras 10 caracteres luego de eso ya es hora

Comment: Basado en tu idea, y en otros, he creado un trigger: **IF NEW.Horax = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
SET NEW.Horax = NOW();
END IF ** pero solo me 8 caracteres y solo la fecha, quisiera solo la hora.